# Zsh array of strings in for loop

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh

Am trying to print a bunch of strings in a script (in `zsh`) and it doesn't seem to work. The code would work if I place the array in a variable and use it instead. Any ideas why this doesn't work otherwise?

`for string in (some random strings to print) ; echo $string`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The default form of the `for` command in *zsh* does not use parentheses (if there are any they are not interpreted as part of the `for` statement):

```
for string in some random strings to show
do
    echo _$string
done
```

This results in the following output:

```
_some
_random
_strings
_to
_show
```

So, `echo _$string` was run for each word after `in`. The list ends with the newline.

It is possible to write the whole statement in a single line:

```
for string in some random strings to show; do echo _$string; done
```

As usual when putting multiple shell commands in the same line, newlines just need to be replaced by `;`. The exception here is the newline after `do`; while `zsh` allows a `;` to be placed after `do`, it is usually not done, and in `bash` it would be a syntax error.

There are also several short forms available for `for`, all of which are equivalent to the default form above and produce the same output:

- for single commands (to be exact: single pipelines or multiple pipelines linked with `&&` or `||`, where a pipeline can also be just a single command), there are two options:

  - the default form, just without `do` or `done`:

    ```
     for string in some random strings to show ; echo _$string
    ```
  - without `in` but with parentheses, also without `do` or `done`

    ```
     for string (some random strings to show) ; echo _$string
    ```
- for a list of commands (like in the default form), `foreach` instead of `for`, no `in`, with parentheses and terminated by `end`:

  ```
  foreach string (some random strings to show) echo _$string ; end
  ```

---

In your case, you mixed the two short forms for single commands. Due to the presence of `in`, *zsh* did not take the parentheses as a syntactic element of the `for` command. Instead they are interpreted as a glob qualifier. Aside from the fact that you did not intend any filename expansions, this fails for two reasons:

- there is no pattern (with or without actual globs) before the glob qualifier. So any matching filename would have to exactly match an empty string, which is just not possible
- but mainly "some random strings to print" is not a valid glob qualifier. You probably get an error like "zsh: unknown file attribute: i" (at least with *zsh 5.0.5*, it may depend on the *zsh* version).

Comment: Great answer! But I think it could be much improved with some example outputs, even if they seem trivial

Answer (score 12):

Check the `zsh` [`for`loop documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-for-loops):

```
for x (1 2 3);  do echo $x; done
for x in 1 2 3; do echo $x; done
```

Comment: I know that we can use variable to do this; I am asking if there is a way to avoid using it?

Comment: What is wrong with `for x (1 2 3); do echo $x; done` and `for x in 1 2 3; do echo $x; done` ?

Comment: Wow! Thats exactly right! No need for `in` when using array in place? Can you please update the answer, I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably trying to do this:

```
for string in some random strings to print ;do
   echo $string
done
```